# I want to use this font family: PTSansRegular

Tags: theming

I want to use this font family: PTSansRegular for my website.

Do I have to instal the module: @font-your-face ?

or is there another easier way to insal it for my site?

(I found it here http://www.afontz.com/font/paratype/pt-sans/regular/)
(i'm using boilerplate subtheme)

thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, doing it using a module such as [@font-your-face](https://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) or just simply doing it without a module.

- Download the font from the site you specified above.
- Open the CSS from the folder and check the different styles of fonts.
- Copy the font folder to the CSS folder in your theme's directory.
- Open .info file of your Drupal theme and add the stylesheet link from
  the font folder.
- Use the font-family of the currenlyt downloaded font in your
  stylesheet.
- Clear your cache.

Comment: what do you mean with :'add the stylesheet link from the font folder'?  I dont have a link

Comment: I wrote this by my .info file: stylesheets[all][] = css/compiled/PT Sans Regular                                             Is it good like this?